# get cell values of variable cells in messagebox

Tags: vba, messagebox

I have a table with names and skills where 1 means "you dont have this skill" and 3 "you have this skill". When I change it from 1 to 3 you get a msgbox saying: are you sure you want to do this. I want the names and the skills in the msgbox, but don't know how.

so for example I change cell D12 from 1 to 3. The message should say:

Are you sure you want to change (value of cell D1 / the skill) of (value of cell A12 / the name of the person)

That's ok. But it is applicable on the active cell though, so the D1 and A12 change depending on which cell is active. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [R1C1 Reference Style](http://www.lytebyte.com/2008/04/29/what-are-a1-and-r1c1-reference-style-in-excel/). In this case you'll have to switch the settings of Excel to R1C1 Reference style:

In **Office 2007**, Click the **Office** button and click **Excel Options** which you will find at the end near **Exit Excel**.

Go to **Formulas** tab and under **Working with formulas**, Check **R1C1 reference style** to use it.

If you specify formula like `=R[2]C[1]` in `A1` cell, it will return you a value from `B3` cell.

The second way is to use the following formula:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN())),2,1)
```

In this case you don't have to change any settings

***EDIT:***

I tried your example. If you want to achieve this by using VBA it's even easier:

```
Dim skillValue As String
skillValue = Range(Cells(1, Selection.Column), Cells(1, Selection.Column))
Dim nameValue As String
nameValue = Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1), Cells(Selection.Row, 1))
If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to change " & skillValue & " of " & nameValue & "?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then
...............
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. But this doensn't work on various cells right? For example: For cell C3 I want the information in C1 (R[-2]C[0]) and A3 (R[0]C[-2]). But with the same formula i want the info for other cells ex. for D12 I want the cell value of D1 and A12

Comment: ..not yet, i pressed the enter a bit to quickly. I edited my reply

Comment: Take a look on named ranges then

Comment: here's an example : http://temp.shizihou.nl/temp_name_skill.xls

I'll take a look at the named ranges. thanks

Comment: @user1670865 I've updated my answer, replace the header of your `CommandButton1_Click`